# What is the difference between 討論 and 議論?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

As part of my research, I came across the following explanation [here](https://hinative.com/questions/1236273):

> 討論 is a discussion or a debate at one place.
> 討議 consists of several discussions for a specific subject.
> 議論 is more general word. It can be used similar to 討論, or a piece of 討議.

As I understand it, 討論 means the event as a whole whereas 議論 is the actual content of the debate, i.e. the argumentation. But I still don't understand well the difference between these words. Which one would be closer to 話し合い ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last question is easy to answer:  議論 is closer.

The character 討 carries a connotation of “battle”. 討論 certainly assumes there are opposing sides and possibly also that there will be a winner. For example, a debate between heads of political parties is 党首討論.

議論 is a more general term for discussion. Being a word of Chinese formation (kango), it has a formal sound to it, but it basically means the same as 話し合い when it refers to a concrete occasion where multiple people actually discuss something.

議論 can also be used in a more abstract sense, corresponding to the second definition of “debate” in the following excerpt from New Oxford American Dictionary. (The first definition corresponds to 討論.)

> **debate** | dəˈbeɪt |
> noun
>
> a formal discussion on a particular topic in a public meeting or legislative assembly, in which opposing arguments are put forward: *last night's **debate on** the Education Bill.*
>
> • an argument about a particular subject, especially one in which many people are involved: *the national **debate on** education* | *there has been much debate about prices.*